# Firefox Dev Edition: shorter XPATH finder

Tags: xpath, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

how is it possible to easily obtain short form of XPATH through **Inspector**?
For example, if I try "Copy xpath" on web element I get pretty long response like this:

*/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/p[13]*

Instead of this or similar:

*//*[@id='exeample_value']*

Since I need to cover a lot of these, do not want to loose time to shorten them manually. In older versions of Firefox I used plugins like **Firebug** and **Firepath**, but they seem not to be compatible with new **FF** versions (and **FF Dev Edition**).

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools don't allow to copy relative XPaths yet (as of Firefox 58). Therefore I've filed [bug 1410810](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1410810) for it some time ago.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have Firefox 59 and seems that the thing is not covered yet.

Comment: Yes, the bug report is still open, that means it is also not available in Firefox 60, unfortunately, which is currently in Nightly channel. I just wrote 58, because that's the current stable version of Firefox. If you want to support that, you can vote for it.